# Hudson + Maven + Emma/Sonar = Build Cycle Runs 2x

Tags: hudson, maven-3, sonarqube

I have a bunch of Maven projects building in Hudson with Sonar sitting in the side-lines. Sonar gives me Sonar stats, FindBugs stats, and code-coverage.

I've noticed that regardless of if I use Sonar or if I use EMMA via Maven directly, **the entire build cycle runs twice.** This includes init (which in my case, reinitializes the database -- expensive) and unit tests (a few hundred -- also expensive).

How can I prevent this? I did a lot of reading, and it seems like this is due to the design of code-coverage plugins -- to keep uninstrumented classes separated from instrumented ones.

I've tried configurations like:

- Maven runs: deploy, EMMA
- Maven runs: deploy; deploy to Sonar on completion

Answer (score 1):

The sonar [documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyse+with+Maven) recommends running the sonar plugin in 2 stages:-

> mvn clean install -Dtest=false -DfailIfNoTests=false
>
> mvn sonar:sonar

The tests are bypassed in the first phase and run implicitly in the second stage.

A one line alternative is to run the following command:-

```
mvn clean install sonar:sonar -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true
```

but this will run the tests twice - as you have found.

Comment: I don't run mvn manually; I do it through Hudson. How does that translate into this solution?

Answer (score 1):

To add to @Strawberry's answer, you could reuse the unit test reports instead of running them again.  Refer to the section Reuse existing unit test reports in the [sonar documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyse+with+Maven)

Once this is done, you can configure the following in Hudson

```
clean deploy sonar:sonar
```